# Determine cell type of multidimensional structure based on indexPath.section and indexPath.row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

These are my structs:

```
struct Category{
    var category_name = String()
    var items = [Item]()
}

struct Item{
    var rows = [Row]()
}

struct Row{
    var size: Int
}
```

I have a menu object which is an array of Categories:

var menu = [Category]

I populate the menu, and have a structure like this:

```
-category1 // section 0, row 0
    -item1 // section 0, row 1
        -row1 // section 0, row 2
        -row2 // section 0, row 3
    -item2 // section 0, row 4
    -item3 // section 0, row 5
-category2 // section 1, row 0
    -item1 // section 1, row 1
    -item2 // section 1, row 2
        -row1 // section 1, row 3
        -row2 // section 1, row 4
        -row3 // section 1, row 5
    -item3 // section 1, row 6
        -row1 // section 1, row 7
```

I want to populate a `UITableView` with cells appropriate for the type of row in the structure, based on the index in the section.

So in the example above, section 0 row 0 = category1. So I should return a cell appropriate for a category heading. Section 1 row 5 = item2->row3, so I should return a subrow cell.

Row 0 will always equal a category cell, but for a given section index and row index, how can I determine the type of cell in the structure?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0{ // category cell type
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_category") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.textLabel?.text = menu[indexPath.section].category_name
        return cell
    }else{// item cell type or subrow
        // based on indexPath.section and indexPath.row, 
        // should we return an item cell or a subrow cell?
        if ( ??? ){ // item cell type
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_item") else {return UITableViewCell()}
            return cell
        }else{ // subrow cell type
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_subrow") else {return UITableViewCell()}
            return cell
        }
    }
```

So these are my expected values for the example above:

```
indexPath.section = 0
indexPath.row = 0
return cell type = cell_category

indexPath.section = 0
indexPath.row = 1
return cell type = cell_item

indexPath.section = 0
indexPath.row = 2
return cell type = cell_subrow
```

numberOfRowsInSection is returning the correct number of rows.

**So how can I determine what type of cell to return?**

I think I need to loop through the items and keep a counter, but I can't figure out a logical way to do so.

Comment: Can you label the section and row in your example with comments?

Comment: Ok, I added those comments

Comment: Ok, so now i understand you are not using section headers. Is there is a pattern in how you choose your cells? Like how do you know which cell comes after which? Do you have an array which holds the order or a specific pattern that the cells follow?

Comment: It's dynamic so it will change often. So based on any current structure and a section value and a row value I need to determine the cell type.

Comment: So you will have the row type stored somewhere in an array which will have information on which row has what cell correct?

Comment: The type is not specifically stored as a value, but it is inherent in the data. In my example data, menu[0].items[0].count == 2, and menu[0].items[1].count == 0. I think I can use a loop, a counter, and these .count values to determine the cell type given a row, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I'm really sorry man. It was a long day yesterday. So couldn't think straight and understand your question. Your question is pretty well explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top my head, this is what i have. Iterate through the array and identify what cell appears for each index path an store it. Let's say taking this example into account, we have an enum.

```
enum cellType {
    case category
    case item
    case row
}
```

Now you build the array which has the cell type for each section.

```
var cells: [cellType] = []
for category in menu {
     cells.append(.category)
     if !category.items.isEmpty {
          cells.append(.item)
          for item in items {
              if !category.items.rows.isEmpty {
                  for row in category.items.rows {
                       cells.append(.row)
                  }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Now use the cells array to find the type of cell to be dequeued.

This is a really ugly implementation, but it should work. Or atleast you'd know how to start.

Comment: Nice, this makes sense.